# Show that these inclusions are correct

Tags: linear-algebra

Let say that S,T and U are subspaces of V. How can I show these inclusions?

a) $S\cap U\subseteq(S+T)\cap U$ and $T\cap U\subseteq(S+T)\cap U \\$

b) $(S\cap U)+( T\cap U) \subseteq(S+T)\cap U$

I have no idea how to start. Any help?

Comment: Use the additive identity of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

a. Let $v\in S\cap U$. Then $v=v+0\in S+T$, as $v\in S$ and $0\in T$. Hence $v\in S+T$ and $v\in U$, so $v\in (S+T)\cap U$. The second inclusion of a. follows by renaming the spaces.

b. Let $v\in (S\cap U)+(T\cap U)$. Then $v=x+y$, where $x\in S\cap U$ and $y\in T\cap U$. Notice that in particular, we have $x,y\in U$, so also $x+y\in U$ (as $U$ is a vector space). As $x+y=v$, we obtain $v\in U$. Also, w clearly have $v\in S+T$ (as $v=x+y$ and $x\in S$ and $y\in T$). Hence we conclude $v\in (S+T)\cap U$. This proves the desired inclusion.

This is of course quite unreadable because of all the details, but that's how one does it rigorously. :-)

Answer (score 0):

a). $S\subseteq S+T$ for each $S,T$. Intersection is monotonous w.r.t. inclusion. Thus $S\cap U\subseteq (S+T)+U$. The other inclusion is similar.